# ¿Cómo capturar y enviar datos a un controlador C# a través de un click (o cualquier evento javascript) en un documento Html hosteado en un WebBrowser?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, eventos, navegador-web

soy principiante en la plataforma .NET y tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando con WPF y usando la componente WebBrowser para cargar documentos HTML (con su respectivo javascript, css, etc.) que se encuentran en mi PC, y no se cómo capturar eventos ocurridos en la vista (ya sea onClick, keyPress, etc) para comunicarle a C# (a mi MainWindow.xaml.cs), enviarle parámetros y este se encargue de manejar la lógica del negocio (p.ej. insertar en base de datos o consultar). Hago uso de WebBrowser.InvokeScript(...) en algunas ocasiones para ejecutar funciones implementadas en javascript que se encuentran en la página hosteada:

```
...

     try
        {
           result =  wbSample.InvokeScript("Obtener").ToString();
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
           catch (Exception ex)
        {...
    //donde wbSample es al componente visual WebBrowser
```

pero no me sirve ya que es el accionar de un botón, por ejemplo, el que debe desencadenar el flujo, hacer la petición al controlador (en C#) y este se encargue del resto. Este botón por supuesto es una componente del DOM. Gracias le doy de antemano a todo aquel que se interese por esta pregunta y espero puedan ayudar.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, trata de ser lo mas claro posible ya que no se puede saber que quieres realmente recomendación [Como escribir preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es bastante clara

Answer (score 0):

aquí explico como resolví el problema que tenía, esta fue la solución que encontré. Primeramente tenía que hacer que los métodos controladores (C#) fueran visibles, por decirlo de alguna forma, desde el código javascript, y esto lo logré así:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using BusinessLogic;
using WebBrowserApp.Models;
using WebBrowserApp.DataAccess.Implementations;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace WebBrowserApp.Presentation
{
    .........
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly IFacturaBL facturaService;

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public class ScriptManager
        {
            private MainWindow windowd;

            public ScriptManager(MainWindow window)
            {
                this.windowd = window;
            }


            public bool remove(int Id)
            {

                var context = new WebBrowserApp.DataAccess.WebBrowserAppContext<Factura, int>();
                var facturaService = new FacturaBL(new Repository<Factura, int>(context), context);

                var result = facturaService.Remove(Id);

                return result;
            }
    //Otros métodos de la clase aquí
    }
..............
}
```

Donde la clase **ScriptManager** contiene todos los métodos que serán visibles desde javascript. Luego para acceder desde la vista lo hacemos de la siguiente forma:

```
function remove(facturaId) {
    var removeFacturaResult = window.external.remove(facturaId);
    if (removeFacturaResult)
        window.location = "index.html";
    else
        alert("Failed");
}
```

Es claro que esta función podrá ser invocada a partir de cualquier evento que deseemos y que fuera desencadenado en la página web.